# Electron / NodeJS and application freezing on setInterval / async code

Tags: node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, electron

I'm working on an [electron](http://electron.atom.io) application that performs a screenshot capture every 3 seconds with the electron api, and writes it to a given target path. I've set up a separate BrowserWindow where the capturing code runs in (see code structure below) a setInterval() "loop", but whenever the capture happens, the app freezes for a moment. I think it is the call to `source.thumbnail.toPng()` or `writeScreenshot()` method in the file `ScreenCapturer.jshtml.js`.

I set up this structure as I though this was the way to go, but apparently this is not. WebWorkers won't help me either as I need node modules such as fs, path and desktopCapturer (from electron).

How would one do this type of task without blocking the main thread every time the interval code (as seen in file `ScreenCapturer.jshtml.js`) runs (because I thought the renderer processes were separate processes?)

---

### My code as reference

**main.js** (main process)

```
// all the imports and other
// will only show the import that matters
import ScreenCapturer from './lib/capture/ScreenCapturer';  

app.on('ready', () => {
   // Where I spawn my main UI
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({...});
   mainWindow.loadURL(...);
   // Other startup stuff

   // Hee comes the part where I call function to start capturing
   initCapture();
});

function initCapture() {
    const sc = new ScreenCapturer();
    sc.startTakingScreenshots();
}
```

**ScreenCapturer.js** (module used by main process)

```
'use strict';

/* ******************************************************************** */
/* IMPORTS */
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron';
import url from 'url';
import path from 'path';
/* VARIABLES */
let rendererWindow;
/*/********************************************************************///
/*///*/

/* ******************************************************************** */
/* SCREENCAPTURER */
export default class ScreenCapturer {
    constructor() {
        rendererWindow = new BrowserWindow({
            show: true, width: 400, height: 600,
            'node-integration': true,
            webPreferences: {
                webSecurity: false
            }
        });                        
        rendererWindow.on('close', () => {
            rendererWindow = null;
        });
    }

    startTakingScreenshots(interval) {
        rendererWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
            rendererWindow.openDevTools();
            rendererWindow.webContents.send('capture-screenshot', path.join('e:', 'temp'));
        }); 
        rendererWindow.loadURL(
            url.format({
                pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'ScreenCapturer.jshtml.html'),
                protocol: 'file:',
                slashes: true
            })
        );                       
    }    
}
/*/********************************************************************///
/*///*/
```

**ScreenCapturer.jshtml.js** (the thml file loaded in the renderer browser window)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>require('./ScreenCapturer.jshtml.js')</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ScreenCapturer.jshtml.js** (the js file loaded from the html file in the renderer process)

```
import { ipcRenderer, desktopCapturer, screen } from 'electron';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import moment from 'moment';
let mainSource;

function getMainSource(mainSource, desktopCapturer, screen, done) {
    if(mainSource === undefined) {
        const options = {
            types: ['screen'],
            thumbnailSize: screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
        };
        desktopCapturer.getSources(options, (err, sources) => {
            if (err) return console.log('Cannot capture screen:', err);
            const isMainSource = source => source.name === 'Entire screen' || source.name === 'Screen 1';
            done(sources.filter(isMainSource)[0]);        
        });
    } else {
        done(mainSource);
    }
}
function writeScreenshot(png, filePath) {
    fs.writeFile(filePath, png, err => {        
        if (err) { console.log('Cannot write file:', err); }
        return;       
    });
}

ipcRenderer.on('capture-screenshot', (evt, targetPath) => {    
    setInterval(() => {          
        getMainSource(mainSource, desktopCapturer, screen, source => {
            const png = source.thumbnail.toPng();
            const filePath = path.join(targetPath, `${moment().format('yyyyMMdd_HHmmss')}.png`);
            writeScreenshot(png, filePath);
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

---

Comment: I'm having this problem too

Comment: @Booligoosh it's a pain indeed, but I walked away from using this. I'd recommend using `desktop-screenshot` package -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/desktop-screenshot. This worked cross platform (linux, mac, win) for me.

Comment: @Booligoosh see my answer below, it might be of use for you maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/43113931/1155847

Answer (score 2):

I walked away from using the API's delivered by electron. I'd recommend using `desktop-screenshot` package -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/desktop-screenshot. This worked cross platform (linux, mac, win) for me.
**Note** on `windows` we need the [`hazardous` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hazardous), because otherwise when packaging your electron app with an `asar` it won't be able to execute the script inside `desktop-screenshot`. More info on the hazardous package's page.

Below is how my code now roughly works, please don't copy/paste because it might not fit your solution!! However it might give an indication on how you could solve it.

```
/* ******************************************************************** */
/* MODULE IMPORTS */
import { remote, nativeImage } from 'electron';
import path from 'path';
import os from 'os';
import { exec } from 'child_process';
import moment from 'moment';
import screenshot from 'desktop-screenshot';
/* */
/*/********************************************************************///
/* ******************************************************************** */
/* CLASS */
export default class ScreenshotTaker {    
    constructor() {
        this.name = "ScreenshotTaker";        
    }
    start(cb) {
        const fileName = `cap_${moment().format('YYYYMMDD_HHmmss')}.png`;
        const destFolder = global.config.app('capture.screenshots');
        const outputPath = path.join(destFolder, fileName);        
        const platform = os.platform();
        if(platform === 'win32') {
            this.performWindowsCapture(cb, outputPath);
        }
        if(platform === 'darwin') {
            this.performMacOSCapture(cb, outputPath);
        }
        if(platform === 'linux') {
            this.performLinuxCapture(cb, outputPath);
        }
    }
    performLinuxCapture(cb, outputPath) {
        // debian
        exec(`import -window root "${outputPath}"`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if(error) {
                cb(error, null, outputPath);
            } else {
                cb(null, stdout, outputPath);
            }
        });
    }
    performMacOSCapture(cb, outputPath) {
        this.performWindowsCapture(cb, outputPath);
    }
    performWindowsCapture(cb, outputPath) {
        require('hazardous');
        screenshot(outputPath, (err, complete) => {
            if(err) {
                cb(err, null, outputPath);
            } else {
                cb(null, complete, outputPath);
            }
        });
    }
}
/*/********************************************************************///
```